# Where can I find the auto export output?

Tags: firebug

[image]I have a script which runs infinitely and outputs some information from Firebug. I would like Firebug to append this info to the log. I am using auto export but I couldn't find where auto export saves script output.

So, where can I find auto export output log?

Comment: Do you mean the [*Console* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel) log? Which auto export are you talking about? Please clarify that in your question. Maybe you could also append a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: yes I mean conole Auto Export . Where can be log default location ?

Comment: Note that the *Console* panel doesn't have an export option by default. So, according to your screenshot you must have the extension *ConsoleExport* installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you are using the Firebug extension [ConsoleExport](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#ConsoleExport).

The *Auto Export* option there sends the data to a server URL, which can be specified with the preference `extensions.firebug.consoleexport.serverURL` (can be changed via [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config)). The data is sent in XML format.

A [detailed description](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/consoleexport/) of how to set up the auto-export and what data is sent can be found at the blog of Jan 'Honza' Odvarko.

Note that there is currently no option to save the data on the local file system, though there is a [feature request](https://github.com/firebug/consoleexport/issues/9) for that, which got already implemented.
So, with the next release there will be a preference `extensions.firebug.consoleexport.logFilePath` allowing you to specify a file path, to which the data is exported.